# How do I pinpoint where the error is in Applescript?

Tags: applescript

Whenever I got an error from `osascript`, it looks like this:
`698:699: syntax error: Expected end of line, etc. but found identifier. (-2741)`

How can I figure out where this error is (a general approach)? I don't have 698 lines in my code, and commenting every line out isn't very practical.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117891/discussion-on-question-by-james10424-how-do-i-pinpoint-where-the-error-is-in-app). We can discuss on [meta] if people have vote to close issues or suggestions on this class of question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run it in the Script Editor, the error will highlight.

Example using image of a random script from an earlier answer

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I honestly would not do much in AppleScript if it were not for the amazing debugger that Late Night Software offers.

- https://latenightsw.com/

The free tier is super powerful and I’ve never regretted paying for the full version when it saves me time and headache. Not only does it show the error location, it has contextual help to guide you on fixing the error.